# LyftSDK.ResponseType.unauthorized Error #20

Tags: ios, swift, lyft-api

I am using lyft sdk and i have already config their develop account key in appdeligate... 
but when i am call this method i always getting this Response below is my code

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.7833, longitude: -122.4167)

       LyftAPI.rideTypes(at: location) { result in
           result.value?.forEach { rideType in
               print(rideType.displayName)
           }
       }
```

When i am trying to calling this method everytime i m got this error
please

```
▿ Result<Array<RideType>, LyftAPIError>
  ▿ failure : LyftAPIError
    - message : nil
    - reason : "unknown"
    ▿ status : Optional<ResponseType>
      - some : LyftSDK.ResponseType.unauthorized
```